# Why jQuery puts equals in whitespaces when I try to append some String

Tags: jquery

I have this string:

```
var strAppend ="<button id='btnUEN' class='k-primary' onclick='getCategoryByUEN(" + stronClick +  ")'>"+ name +" </button>"
$("#nav_clacom_1474").append(strAppend);
```

I did put a `console.log` to `strAppend` and I have this value:

```
<button id='btnUEN' class='k-primary' onclick='getCategoriaByUEN('1','TEST AND TEST')'>TEST AND TEST</button>
```

But the HTML code don't look well... show this:

```
<button id='btnUEN' class='k-primary' onclick='getCategoriaByUEN('1','TEST'="" AND="" TEST')'="">TEST AND TEST</button>
```

Why and how I can resolve this...

Comment: You're not properly escaping your quotes

Comment: Protip: Single quotes for JS, double for HTML. Never deal with this issue again.

Comment: @isherwood Given that they have inline bindings, regardless of if you used single or double quotes on the string, at some point you would have to escape some quotes for the inline binding.  Edit: Which is just one more reason to *not use inline bindings*.

Comment: True. I missed that because I haven't done so in years. David, use event handlers in your script instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to escaping strings. What's happening is that you have a [delimiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) causing your HTML to behave differently than you expected.

In this case, your single quotes inside the onclick attribute are causing the onclick's single quotes surrounding the attribute to prematurely end, because they are behaving as delimiters. To prevent this from happening, you have to escape those delimiters by adding a backslash.

Here's a workaround to replace all `'` with `\'` inside your variable.

```
var stronClick_escaped = stronClick.replace(/'/g, "\\'")
var strAppend ="<button id='btnUEN' class='k-primary' onclick='getCategoryByUEN(" + stronClick_escaped +  ")'>"+ name +" </button>"
$("#nav_clacom_1474").append(strAppend);
```

The reason I replaced it with `"\\'"` is because `\` is an escape character! So you have to escape it, too.

Edit: The quotation marks that cause your strings to prematurely end are delimiters, and the characters inside the string that are escaped are escape characters.

Comment: Based on his code, he is already has quote characters in his variable `stronClick`. Otherwise, how would he have printed `onclick='getCategoriaByUEN('1','TEST AND TEST')'`?

Comment: Ah, I missed that the variable actually contains a substring of the input arguments.  Which actually in this case then he'd just need to swap the `'` in the value for `"` and it would work.

Comment: In either case, both would need to be escaped. Because strAppend is surrounded with double quotes.